# Why does SCRAM-based authentication fails when I try to generate Entities from Tables with JPA?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, authentication, jpa

I'm on a JPA project and when I first generated entities from my PostgreSQL database, everything worked fine. Now I added a table and wanted to correspondingly generate another entity from that one, but Eclipse suddenly tells me that no connection could be established. I'm still using the same database, the same version of PostgreSQL and the same connection.

> Could not connect to [Connection name].
> Error creating SQL Model Connection connection to [Connection name].
> (Error: The server requested SCRAM-based authentication, but no
> password was provided.)

When I run my application, queries and everything work well. Why does it not work for the generation of entities from tables and how do I set the password to make it work? (Of course, I provided it in persistence.xml - is there another location or do I have to explicitly mark it with some kind of "SCRAM-based authentication" tag?)

Comment: Ok, thanks. On your advice, I did so. Do you think, the new title is better? Or did you notice more things I should improve?

Comment: Add your code, if want help.  Can't help if we do not know what you are doing,

Comment: Which code? Well, maybe I wasn't very precise in my description, but it's a built-in Eclipse tool that tells me that Eclipse can't establish a connection (-> Context menu of the application -> JPA Tools -> Generate Entities from Tables -> Select Tables View and there I cannot select any tables because the connection can't be established due to the error I described in my post). It's not an exception that occurs when I run my program!

Comment: And if you are talking about the persistence.xml when you say "code": Obviously I entered everything needed for a working connection, because it does work, when I run my application - only in that one case of generating entities from tables, the server asks for SCRAM-based authentication. There is no indication of SCRAM anywhere in the persistence.xml or elsewhere.